# How to rename multiple filenames in cshell script?

Tags: unix, csh

I have a c shell script which has the following two lines, it creates a directory and copies some files into it. My question is the following - the files being copied look like this `abc.hello`, `abc.name`, `abc.date`, etc... How can i strip the `abc` and just copy them over as `.hello`, `.name`, `.date`.. and so forth. I'm new to this.. any help will be appreciated!

```
mkdir -p $home_dir$param    
cp /usr/share/skel/* $home_dir$param
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something like [basename](http://linux.die.net/man/1/basename):

In Bash, for example, you could get the base name, file suffix like this:

```
filepath=/my/folder/readme.txt
filename=$(basename "$filepath")  # $filename == "readme.txt"
extension="${filename##*.}"       # $extension == "txt"
rootname="${filename%.*}"         # $rootname == "readme"
```

ADDENDUM:

1. The key takeaway is "basename".  Refer to the "man basename" page I linked to above.  Here's another example that should make things clearer:

   `basename readme.txt .txt         # prints "readme"`
2. "basename" is a standard *nix command.  It works in any shell; it's available on most any platform.
3. Going forward, I would strongly discourage you from writing scripts in csh, if you can avoid it:

   - [bash vs csh vs others - which is better for application maintenance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317247/bash-vs-csh-vs-others-which-is-better-for-application-maintenance)
   - [Csh Programming Considered Harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/)

Comment: The OP specifically says `csh`. Your solution is for `bash`.