# Encoding rest path variable in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, rest, angular-ui, angularjs-routing, restful-url

I am having a peculiar issue.
I am calling a restful service with path param from angularjs controller/service.
Below is the url format

```
/payment/{id}/credit/{creditId}/fetch/options
```

Now, creditId has special charachters in it for eg 'abcd%xyz-433'
I am calling a service which makes a GET rest call as below in angualarjs controller

```
creditService.creditOption('abc','abcd%xyz-433').success(function(data, status) {
                $log.log('log the status ' + status);

            });
```

The service is as below

```
creditOption: function(id, creditId) {

                return $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: '/payment/'+id+'/credit/'+creditId+'/fetch/options'
                });
            }
```

The Restful service signature is as follows

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/payment/{id}/credit/{creditId}/fetch/options", produces = APPLICATION_JSON)
    public boolean getCreditOption(@PathVariable String id, @PathVariable String creditId) {

return true
}
```

This is giving me 404 all the time i execute this code. But when i remove the special charachters it works fine and hits the restful service. I also tried to use encodeURIComponent() and then send the value.. but it is still the same case. 
Please let me know if there is any way out for this. 
Thanks for any help

Comment: What is the actual URL being sent on the wire?

Comment: The url is as below  http://monish.home.com/payment/9a2c1ae67d4ff85e561679fcff/credit/%252B8VMWjYBC%252FNj3l/fetch/options

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily an angular issue. You should be able to make this request with just your browser. What do the server logs show as the incoming address?

Answer (score 0):

The `%` symbol is used for encoding values in URls, see [rfc3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) section 2.1. In particular it's expected that there will be two hex digits after the `%` - which it seems like you are exactly stumbling on to.

You may have to escape the percent (use `%25`) or choose a different character to substitute.

You can try it on this page, the address is:

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27641286/encoding-rest-path-variable-in-angularjs`

A `1` percent encoded is `%31`, so you could just as easily go here:

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764%31286/encoding-rest-path-variable-in-angularjs`

Comment: I tried that before using encodeURIComponent() and it generated the below url http://monish.home.com/payment/9a2c1ae67d4ff85e561679fcff/credit/%252B8VMWjYBC%252FNj3l/fetch/options  it still throws the same 404 exception.. i dont understand even after encoding why this issue...any help would be appreciated

Comment: So `/payment/9a2c1ae67d4ff85e561679fcff/credit/%2B8VMWjYBC%2FNj3l/fetch/options` is the unencoded path you're trying to get to? It doesn't seem like this is an issue with Angular. You should be able to get a response from the route with your browser directly and as you've experienced I get no response even with the encoded uri.

Comment: Just for kicks I put a file `foo%bar.html` at `jrussell.me/a/test/foo%bar.html`, you should be able to see it at http://jrussell.me/a/test/foo%25bar.html.

Comment: the url which i have provided is the encoded version using encodeURIComponent() to encode the id and creditid parameters and then creating an url but that doesnt seem to work

Comment: The issue is about the '/' included in the creditId value. If we remove the '/' it seems to work.. so is there a way in angularjs to escape '/' in the value ..

Comment: It's not so much an Angular issue as general URI syntax. See section 2.2 of the RFC mentioned above (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.2), if I read that correctly it says you must percent encode a '/' if you want it to be part of a uri component. If it's going to work at all I think your best bet for '/' would be '%2F'. If you're worried about having other reserved characters in your IDs you may want to create a service to sanitized them.

Comment: I have fixed this issue and there is a peculiar solution to this..           1. You have encode the creditId encodeURIComponent() for eg encodeURIComponent(creditId)                                             2. Secondly you have to encode the whole url in service using encodeURI() for eg encodeURI('/payment/'+id+'/credit/'+creditId+'/fetch/options') ..remember here encodeURIComponent doesnt work hence use the first option of encodeURI().. Now this sanitizes the whole url and will work fine